# Shortening time for repeated renders on cycles for animations

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, optimization

### 1 Frame rendered in Cycles with original settings (~11sec)

[image: ref image Cycles]

---

### 1 Frame rendered in Cycles with thibsert's suggestion (~6sec-8sec)

[image]

- Clip rendered in Cycles for reference (forgot motion blur): https://youtu.be/4a-HzTpflm0

---

### 1 Frame rendered in EEVEE for reference (~330ms)

[image: ref image EEVEE]

- Clip rendered in EEVEE for reference: https://youtu.be/EEczTXhxLjg

---

### 1 Frame rendered in EEVEE after some tweaking with the settings (~1100ms, 128 samples)

[image: ref image EEVEE 2]

- Clip rendered in EEVEE for reference: https://youtu.be/QlL00AvYLk4

---

### 1 Frame rendered in EEVEE after further tweaking (~310ms, 32 samples)

[image: ref image EEVEE]

---

### Relevant settings for thibsert's way:

[image: settings]

The important thing seems to be to **keep samples low** (~*40*) and **use denoising**, previously I tried this option with too many samples (~2000) and noise threshold together with motion blur active which caused problems

**Some issues with this method:**

- The CPU bottlenecks the process while Denoising
- Low samples size might cause problems for indoor scenes (haven't tried yet)
- The GPU & CPU usage spikes up and down for each frame render (idk if relevant, just wanted to point that out)

---

### Relevant settings for the tweaked EEVEE frame:

1. Changed my point **Light Radius** from 0m to 0.01m which enabled the white bit of intense light at the top of the green ball
2. Enabled & tweaked **Ambient Occlusion** in render settings to get the nice shadow below the green ball (side note: default settings kinda suck)
3. Enabled & tweaked **Screen Space Reflections**, the default settings will give quite similar results to cycles but I wanted less reflection on the ball
4. Added an **Irradiance Volume** that covers the road and baked it, default resolution worked fine for my scene
5. Changed **Shadow Size** to 4096px in render settings

**Some issues with this method:**

- It can look worse up close compared to cycles
- Shadows might be a problem in certain scenes
- The Irradiance volume might have problems when 2+ deforming/animated meshes need to provide indirect lighting to each other, you would prob need to bake it for each frame (However I want to point out that with static meshes it works great when 1 animated object enters a baked area)

### What I'm trying to accomplish (half-achieved):

- Re-rendering the scene with Cycles faster after making changes in the scene (for ex: changing the way the camera moves slightly)
  Alternatively: A way to accomplish better quality with EEVEE at the cost of some render time

**Current Render Times (30fps)**:
~3 *minutes* in EEVEE
~1 *hour* in Cycles

**Old Render Times (30fps)**:
~3-6 *minutes* in EEVEE
~2 *hours* in Cycles

**Side Note:** I would like to try to use *Region Render* but my ball & camera moves in the scene, can I somehow easily change this movement to fake movement that just moves the scene?

Comment: Did you try using Denoising, with a lower noise Threshold?

Comment: I just tried however Denoising seems to be very heavy on the CPU causing a bottleneck. The result is that the time it takes is actually slightly longer for each frame.  Edit: the GPU spikes (~100%) when processing samples and then the CPU goes to ~90-100% while processing the Denoising, going down to ~10% when GPU spikes up again for the next frame

Comment: thibsert I tried your suggestion with some alterations and got better times (reflected in the post now) please make a comment so I can highlight it for anyone looking for an answer here :D

Comment: You shouldn't be rendering at final quality to judge changes you've made.  Render at low quality/resolution until you're happy and then do the final render.  CPU will top out while denoising, there's not really anything that can be done to make it more friendly.

Comment: well I'm just rendering 1 frame or putting same settings in viewport to test, I'm not actually rendering the entire animation at final quality each time xd, I just calculate how much that would take based on how long the average of 2-3 frames I render is, EDIT: I'm currently trying to learn so I don't know what my final settings are for any scene or what I need to change at all

Comment: Your finals will probably be at least 1920x1080, but if you're just testing things out you could probably go as low as 480x270 for now. That will speed things up significantly

Comment: no need, it takes 1-30 seconds to render a frame depending on render engine used, settings, scene and what not, and that is only if I need to render it, otherwize I can use the viewport to observe changes (for ex. EEVEE is so fast the viewport on render is basically as fast as shading for my scene)

Comment: anyway I made some tweaks to EEVEE settings and now it look pretty dope, so I will prob stop testing stuff for now anyway xd

Comment: I won't write an Answer because it was just a quick suggestion, and after that you did all the job ;) Feel free to answer to yourself, I'll upvote it. The CPU/GPU usage is totally fine imho ; I mean, you want your hardware to work at full capacity, don't you ? The downside is that you can't really use the computer for something else during this.

Comment: "Changing Light Path settings, didn't help much (maybe because my scene is so simple?)"> You're right, your scene doesn't need many Bounces (mostly diffuse, no transparencies, no complex lighting). Things would have been really different in an interior scene with some glasses, mirrors, SSS and multiple lights...

Answer (score -2):

## Post Summary:

### Get better quality in EEVEE (in general):

- Change **Shadow Size** to **2048px+**
- Make sure your light source has **>0.01m radius**
- Enable & Tweak **Ambient Occlusion**
- Enable **Screen Space Reflections**
- Add **Irradiance Volume** for indirect lighting

### Speed up render time in Cycles:

- Use **GPU** Computing (in general)
- Lower **samples** count (~**40**) & activate **Denoising** (courtesy of thibsert, specific for my scene)
- Use **Fast Global Illumination** preset for *Light Paths* (specific for my scene)

---

**Side Note:** I won't mark this as the answer because it doesn't really answer the post title question (which is asking for optimizations on repeated renders specifically)